# CSS not display the content correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a social widget for my own blog, but I don't know why when I have everything valid, I mean no syntax error and is not displaying it on my blog correctly?

The code is very long, and I don't think I should include it here?

So I did include the code here http://jsfiddle.net/naKEv/

I'm trying to make it similar to this

[image]

but mine when it displays on my blog is not showing it right.

I'm also using css sprices to combine the pictures, but that is not a problem I guess because if I'm using a table to create the code it still display but not the way it suppose to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fixed the height of `#share_icons` remove that.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naKEv/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Please check your TAG's check this:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script></span></a>
        </th>
```

Your `</th>`, `</span>` & `</a>` are close but not start check.

Comment: Wow I think I messed that up too :(